# Integrating KIE workbench from a Java application

Tags: java, drools, kie

I'm trying to integrate Drools kie workbench with a Java application. I'm Using `jboss-as-7.1.1.Final` as my workbench. Here is the rule definition:

```
package adeveloperdairy.admission;
rule "set isEligible"
ruleflow-group "sample"
lock-on-active true
when
    $p : Student(gpa > 2.0)
then
    System.out.println("GPA is greater than 2..");
    $p.setEligible(true);
end
```

Here is my Java code:

```
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-as7/maven2/adeveloperdiary/Admission/1.0/Admission-1.0.jar";

    String userpassword = "user4:456";
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieRepository kr = ks.getRepository();
    HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
    String authEnc = new Base64Encoder().encode(userpassword.getBytes());
    http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+ authEnc);
    InputStream is = http.getInputStream();
    KieModule kModule = kr.addKieModule(ks.getResources().newInputStreamResource(is));

    KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(kModule.getReleaseId());
    System.out.println(kModule.getReleaseId().toString());

    KieBase kBase = kContainer.getKieBase();
    System.out.println(kBase.getKiePackages());
    System.out.println(kBase.getKiePackage("adeveloperdiary.admission").getRules());
    KieSession kSession = kBase.newKieSession();

    Student s = new Student();
    s.setName("Raj");
    s.setGpa(5.0f); 
    kSession.insert(s);
    kSession.fireAllRules();
```

Here is the Student POJO class:

```
 package adeveloperdiary.admission;

 /**
 * This class was automatically generated by the data modeler tool.
 */

 public class Student implements java.io.Serializable
{

 static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 private java.lang.String name;
 private java.lang.Float gpa;
 private java.lang.Boolean eligible;

 public Student()
 {
 }

 public java.lang.String getName()
 {
  return this.name;
 }

 public void setName(java.lang.String name)
 {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public java.lang.Float getGpa()
 {
  return this.gpa;
 }

 public void setGpa(java.lang.Float gpa)
 {
  this.gpa = gpa;
 }

 public java.lang.Boolean getEligible()
 {
  return this.eligible;
 }

 public void setEligible(java.lang.Boolean eligible)
 {
  this.eligible = eligible;
 }

 public Student(java.lang.String name, java.lang.Float gpa,
     java.lang.Boolean eligible)
 {
  this.name = name;
  this.gpa = gpa;
  this.eligible = eligible;
 }

}
```

I'm able to get the Maven deployment - adeveloperdiary:Admission:1.0, package -  [Package name=adeveloperdiary.admission]
as well as the rule - [Rule name=set isEligible, agendaGroup=MAIN, salience=0, no-loop=false].

But it's not able to execute the rule. May be I'm missing something here.

Comment: Can you provide the `Student` POJO class? moreover, you have not put the rule in any agenda group but you looking for `agendaGroup=admission`

Comment: @piyushj I've added Student POJO class generated by KIE workbench. I've removed the agenda group (ruleflow group) from the rule and is now "MAIN". how can i execute rule passing data(gpa and name) from program?

Comment: change the package name to `adeveloperdiary.admission` instead of `com.simple` in drl file

Comment: I wrote it as "com.simple" only here to make it sound familiar. but in my rule everything is in tact.

Comment: everyone here is familiar thats why we trying to help you, but by giving wrong inputs you making life harder for yourself.

Comment: Fine. I've changed it back. Now tell me how can i execute rule passing data(gpa and name) from program.

Comment: @Raghu I see Student POJO class has been generated by data modeller of kie-workbench. How have you integrated that in your Java code? I suggest you to share the whole class file containing main.

Comment: @NavedAlam i don't know how to access that Student POJO class of workbench from my Java code. And that's where exactly I needed help. Are there any Java API's (or code snippet if you know) to access that POJO class, insert data to an object of it and finally fire the rules ?

Comment: @Raghu Added the step to use POJO in your rules in a new answer. Try whether that works for you.

Comment: @Arjun How you get the .jar file stated in url variable?

Answer (score 2):

I see you are having problem in using the POJO class in your kie workbench. Here are the step to import a simple POJO in workbench and use the same in rule. This has been tested last tested to work with 6.4.0.FINAL version

## Adding external POJO model to the rules

The POJO model class that is needed by the workbench project need to be exported as a maven jar and uploaded to the workbench. If not maven jar, you could export it to a simple jar. If you are using eclipse, it's a simple export.

### Uploading the POJO model class jar

- In kie workbench, go to Authoring -> Artifact Repository -> Upload ->
  Browse to the Jar and upload
- If Jar does not contain a pom.xml file,
  you will be asked to manually enter a group and artifact id.

### Adding model to the Project

- Navigate to the project -> Open Project Editor
- In project editor, from the dropdown, select Dependencies.
- Add from repository -> Select the model class jar file.

### Adding and using model class in Rules.

- Open guided rule editor -> Navigate to the ‘Data Object’ tab.
- New item -> Choose a type.
- The type can be then used in rule editor.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I followed the procedure. But after adding the external jar to the project it shows a popup saying "Unable to complete your request. The following exception occurred: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file." do you know why it's unable to open the jar file? and also i didn't get the last step.

Comment: @Raghu ..which step is giving you above error? How did you create the Jar file? Were you able to see the content of the jar file using some unzipping tool?

Comment: i'm getting this error after adding the external repository to the workbench project as dependency. the workbench becomes very slow. Jar file has been created from maven project in eclipse and I can see the contents of the jar after unzipping it. It is well n good.

Comment: In fact when I try to import Student class from external repository (after adding it to the project as dependency), it gives an error: "myDroolsProject.Student resolves to a package. only type can be added." how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `ruleflow-group "sample"` from your DRL code and try again.

You can test whether correct rules would fire by using a single (!) rule

```
rule "hello"
when
then
    System.out.println( "hello" );
end
```

If this doesn't fire, you have a problem in your setup. If it fires, you have a problem in your rule(s).

Comment: removed ruleflow-group. But no luck. I didn't get how to use single (!) rule. Anyway that doesn't matter here since i'm going with only one rule. Can you figure out where i'm going wrong in the code..?

Comment: @Raghu Just paste the above rule instead of your rule and try running your code. Check if hello is getting printed in java console.

Comment: yes, this rule is firing up from my java program. How can I fire rules for a user defined object (In this case, Student) passing a fact(data) from the program?